Why is the reason which Network Inspector doesn't show response data
I updated my Android Studio a few days ago (Koala) and now is not possible to see data response in Network Inspector, in Iguana not problem I can see data.
I check updates in Koala and I installed all for it , I installed platform tools v35 too and I stopped firewall Windows but I don't achieve to see data in Koala.
Any idea or library that I can delete for install again ?
Thanks in advance

I am facing same issue.

After update Koala to last patch  I can only data from GET request not POST
